# Why c is lowercase in controllers of Magento?

Tags: controllers

Why is `c` lowercase in `controllers` folder name? Whereas Model, Block and Helper are starting with an uppercase letter?

Comment: Hey...why the downvote? This is a legit and actually good question.

Comment: There's a member (I will not tell the name of course) who is flagging/downvoting randomly. For example this question was flagged as offensive :D

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly...yeah I understand that. It seamed offensive to me at start but then I read the question again :)

Comment: Controller with a capital C was already taken haha.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The classes located in the `controllers` folders are a special breed of classes.
You cannot rewrite them in the same way as you rewrite a model or a block using the `<rewrite>` tag in `config.xml`, you cannot instantiate them using a factory like you do for models (`Mage::getModel()`) or with helpers (`Mage::helper`) or with blocks (`Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock()`).
I mean there is `Mage::getControllerInstance()` but that is a bit different. More on this  later.
You may notice that they don't actually follow the naming rule as the other classes.
The work `controllers` is not found in the class name.
Let's take for example the controller found in `Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php`.
The class name is `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController`.
I cannot give you a 100% certain answer, only a core dev can do that.
But my assumption is that someone did not want the controllers to be autoloaded.

Take a look at this method `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match`. It's big and scary, but that's the one that maps an url to a controller and an action.
There are a lot of calculations done but somewhere there is this line:

```
$controllerClassName = $this->_validateControllerClassName($realModule, $controller);
```

If we dig deeper in the `_validateControllerClassName` you will end up in `getControllerFileName` that looks like this:

```
public function getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $realModule);
    $realModule = implode('_', array_splice($parts, 0, 2));
    $file = Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', $realModule);
    if (count($parts)) {
        $file .= DS . implode(DS, $parts);
    }
    $file .= DS.uc_words($controller, DS).'Controller.php';
    return $file;
}
```

and in `_includeControllerClass` that basically does this: `include $controllerFileName;`.

Notice the hard coded `controllers` in the method `getControllerFileName` and notice that the controller file is just included. So no autoloading.

Finally, the controller factory `Mage::getControllerInstance()` does not locate the class and does not look in the rewrites. It just does `return new $class($request, $response, $invokeArgs);` where `$class` is the controller class.

*Side note*: In some modules there is a folder called `Controller` (with capital C) and the classes in follow the standard class naming. Those classes are not really controllers. They are used as parent classes for other controllers in the module or as routers.

*Side note 2* : This does not exist in Magento 2. All controllers are located in the `Controller` folder.

Answer (score 16):

Marius you are so great :D

My answer would just have been:

This is Zend Framework standard: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html

Comment: It's actually a good answer.

Comment: this is a beautiful answer. I think this would be more correct answer than Marius. Because a zend framework developer wouldn't think about another directory other than `controllers` and I assume Mage core team would be a zend framework experts. Kudos. Thanks for sharing that link

Comment: Very help fulll

Comment: Yep I think that this is the correct answer as well. I didn't even bother to look at the ZF standards. I just tried to find a logical explanation. In my defense, I stated in the answer that it was my opinion.